# Create dictionary from successful regex matches in python

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to regex. I am trying to read a log file line by line.And trying to find patterns like below, they can be anywhere on the line , not just the starting.

```
18514&email=dkekrf@yahoo.com"qwqw  (need to extract only email=dkekrf@yahoo.com)
"emailTo":"lolllll@gmail.com"
pseId="12121212ffsd"
```

how can i use re.search to search for all three patterns together ?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your final question...can you be more specific about your input and your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. I hope, it extracts the e-mail address you want.

I could not create a more accurate regex expression, because you did not provide more information about the logfile. Also I am not sure, if I understand your question right.

```
import re

for line in open('filename', 'r'):
    firstPattern = re.search(r'email=(.*?)"', line)
    secondPattern = re.search(r'"emailTo":"(.*?)"', line)
    thirdPattern = re.search(r'pseId="(.*?)"', line)

    if firstPattern:
        print(firstPattern.group(1))
    elif secondPattern:
        print(secondPattern.group(1))
    elif thirdPattern:
        print(thirdPattern.group(1))
```

Comment: I am trying to read a log file line by line .And there are three types of patterns:                                                     18514&email=dkekrf@yahoo.com  (need to extract only email=dkekrf@yahoo.com)
"emailTo":"lolllll@gmail.com"
pseId="12121212ffsd"

Comment: Two patterns work good

for the first one :

    firstPattern = re.search(r'email=(.*?)\s', line)

The pattern should end with a “
example:
    18514&email=dkekrf@yahoo.com"qwqw  (need to extract only email=dkekrf@yahoo.com)

Should match just: dkekrf@yahoo.com

Its currently matching :
    dkekrf@yahoo.com"iqwqwqw

Comment: Now the first pattern should match your string.